# problem with trigger validation test in productive environment

Tags: code-coverage, unexpectedexception

I generated a trigger for one of my clients and I created the test class with a 100% validation of coverage, however, after modifying the code the following error still appears and I can not think of it, how to remove this error

Code:

```
trigger conservaOrigenYSubOrigen on Lead (before update) {
    for(Integer i=0; i<trigger.new.size(); i++)
    {
        //Pregunta si el Origen_de_Contacto__c no es null
        if(trigger.new[i].Origen_de_Contacto__c != null) {
            //si no es null, entonces use el valor previo ("old")
            trigger.new[i].Origen_de_Contacto__c = trigger.old[i].Origen_de_Contacto__c;
        }
        //Pregunta si el Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c no es null
        if(trigger.new[i].Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c != null) {
            //si no es null, entonces use el valor previo ("old")
            trigger.new[i].Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c = trigger.old[i].Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c;}}}
```

Test:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class conservaOrigenYSubOrigenTest{

    public static testMethod void testConOrigen(){

        String uniqueUserName = 'standarUser' + Datetime.now().getTime() + '@testorg.com';
        Profile p = [SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Administrador del sistema'];
        User AdminUser = new User(Alias = 'standt', 
                             Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                             EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', 
                             LastName='Testing', 
                             LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                             LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
                             ProfileId = p.Id,
                             TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
                             UserName=uniqueUserName);


        system.runAs(AdminUser){        

        Lead ejemploLead = New Lead(LastName='BLUECLIP_test1',
                                    Email='consultor1@blueclip.cl',
                                    Company='BLUECLIP_test1',
                                    Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c= 'a0a3I0000004NnAQAU',
                                    Origen_de_Contacto__c= 'a0T3I000000E1jXUAS');

        Insert ejemploLead;
        ejemploLead.Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c = 'a0a3I0000004LGBQA2';
        ejemploLead.Origen_de_Contacto__c = 'a0T3I000000E1jXUAS';
        update ejemploLead;         

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test uses `seeAllData=true` and hard-codes numerous record Ids. Both are very bad practices and establish a dependency between your test class and the specific data in the org in which you originally wrote it.

With hard-coded Ids, your test won't pass outside its original context - i.e., a different org with different data, or the same org after data has been altered. You will need to rewrite your test to ensure that it generates *all* of the data that it needs within its isolated test context, and remove the `seeAllData=true` annotation.

A trigger is likely not the optimal solution for whatever this underlying requirement is. If you wish to prevent changes to the field `Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c`, you should use Field-Level Security or a Validation Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you David. We actually changed the test class so there are no hard coded ids, and we made the test method `private`:

```
@isTest
private class conservaOrigenYSubOrigen_Test{

    private static testMethod void testConOrigen(){

        Test.startTest();
        Origen_de_Contacto__c ejemploOrigenContacto1 = New Origen_de_Contacto__c (Name='Origen Test 1');
        insert ejemploOrigenContacto1;
        Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c ejemploSubOrigenContacto1 = New Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c (Name='SubOrigen Test Origen 1',
                                                                                             Origen_de_Contacto__c =ejemploOrigenContacto1.Id);
        insert ejemploSubOrigenContacto1;

        Lead ejemploLead = New Lead(LastName='BLUECLIP_test1',
                                    Email='consultor1@blueclip.cl',
                                    Company='BLUECLIP_test1',
                                    Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c= ejemploSubOrigenContacto1.Id,
                                    Origen_de_Contacto__c= ejemploOrigenContacto1.Id);

        Insert ejemploLead;

        Origen_de_Contacto__c ejemploOrigenContacto2 = New Origen_de_Contacto__c (Name='Origen Test 2');
        insert ejemploOrigenContacto2;
        Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c ejemploSubOrigenContacto2 = New Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c (Name='SubOrigen Test Origen 2',
                                                                                             Origen_de_Contacto__c =ejemploOrigenContacto2.Id);
        insert ejemploSubOrigenContacto2; 

        ejemploLead.Origen_de_Contacto__c=ejemploOrigenContacto2.Id;
        ejemploLead.Sub_Origen_de_Contacto__c=ejemploSubOrigenContacto2.Id;

        update ejemploLead;   

        Test.stopTest();
        //system.assertEquals(ejemploLead, ejemploLead);

    }

}
```

It worked!